# Issue installing python library via PIP

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip, autoit

I'm trying to install the AutoIT library for Robot Framework. Here's the result I see after downloading the library, extracting it to a folder and running `python setup.py install`:

```
Owner@Owner MINGW64 /c/users/owner/downloads/AutoItLibrary-1.1
$ python setup.py install

%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 70, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 186, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\regsvr32.exe /S C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\AutoItLibrary\lib\AutoItX3.dll' returned non-zero exit status 5
```

Anyone know the reason behind this error?

Comment: Have you tried running this outside of Cygwin or whatever terminal this is?

Comment: It was Git Bash. I just tried powershell and got the same error.

Answer (score -1):

did you do the build first?

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I tried this and despite having python 3 installed saw this:

Comment: The 1st build worked but the install did not. the python3 commands resulted in command not found (even though I have it installed)

Comment: Question was tagged with Python2.7

Comment: Perhaps a better thought would be to ask if you can do this in Python3.   Must it be Python2.7?